# First time return undefined and second the correct result, how can i fix it?

Tags: angular, angular7

i have an issue with call on a webservice by using Angular 7. The call is made on this way on my service :

```
getLogin(usr: String, pwd: String) {
    return this.http.post("the url of webservice", { username: usr, password: pwd 
    });
}
```

and on my component :

```
 credenzialiConfronto() {
this.cred.getLogin(this.loginForm.get("username").value, this.loginForm.get("psw").value).subscribe((res => {
  this.User = res;
}));

console.log(this.User);
```

why it returns `undefined` the first time and the second time not?

EDIT :

on my component i try this now but not work :

https://imgur.com/a/LJ5o4HW

and on my service :

https://imgur.com/gUe3sh5

Comment: Because default initialisation of `User` variable with undefined. and API call takes some time to retrieve data.

Comment: It's async behavior!

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http   have you used  HttpClient or Http?

Comment: HttpClient cause Http is deprecated

Comment: @GiovanniD'Amico Actually it depends! For ex: If you want that value to use then use `if(value)`

Comment: @GiovanniD'Amico If you want an explanation about `why this happens` then have posted duplicate question Or if you facing any problem then update the question according to that!

Comment: No i want a solution cause i can't found it

Comment: @GiovanniD'Amicoc heck on ui if data is exist than show or other option is use `setTimeout`.

Comment: I think set a timeout or do a while cicle is not the better way to do a sync call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because javascript is a `asynchronous` so it will not wait for api call completion.
In your code you log the `User` outside the subscription scope if you log inside the subscription you will get the `user` data first time of the call.
There is nothing wrong with your code.

For making a javascript synchronous you can implement the `async` `await`

```
async callerFunction() {
   await this.credenzialiConfronto();
   console.log(this.User);
}

credenzialiConfronto() {
return new promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  this.cred.getLogin(this.loginForm.get("username").value, 
   this.loginForm.get("psw").value).subscribe((res => {
   this.User = res;
   resolve();
}));
})
```

Comment: i know that js i asynchronous but i try to use subscribe to make it sync. How can i fix it so?

Comment: Okay, for that you can implement the `async` `await`

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code. i will show you how to implement the `async` `await`.

Comment: async and await dont work. What can i do? Where is my misstake?

Comment: is there any error? can you show me what you have done so far.

Comment: In your `credenzialiConfronto` function your return type is not `promise` check my answer in my ans `credenzialiConfronto` return type is promise and inside the subscription i write the `resolve`.

Comment: `resolve` represent success call back means return `true`.

Comment: If my ans help you out accept that so other people get help from that.

Comment: Man it work so fine. Thank you so much! Can u explain me why?

Comment: The Promise.resolve() method returns a Promise object that is resolved with a given value. If the value is a promise, that promise is returned; if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value. This function flattens nested layers of promise-like objects (e.g. a promise that resolves to a promise that resolves to something) into a single layer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you caused a race condition. The first time you log the user, it has not yet been returned by the service. Instead, you can log it like:

```
credenzialiConfronto() {
  this.cred.getLogin(this.loginForm.get("username").value, this.loginForm.get("psw").value)
  .pipe(
    tap(user => console.log(user))
  )
  .subscribe((res => {
    this.User = res;
}));
```

With this change, you only log the user, when the `getLogin` call has returned.

Comment: It not work. Same result as before. It return first time "undefined" and second time my reuslt

Comment: Where do you call `credenzialiConfronto`?

Comment: On submit button on my login page

Comment: You have one `console.log`, inside the `tap` function, and it still returns `undefined`?

Comment: Insiede tap it return  : pipe[object Object].  Outside return "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://angular.io/guide/http)

this should be your service

```
/** POST: data to the database */
login(email, password) : Observable<any>{
return this._http.post<any>(this.APIURL+`login`, { email:email, password:password})
.pipe(map(user => {
  return user;
}));
```

}

this should be you component

```
   this._loginService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.toast.success(data[constants.MESSAGE]);
    },
    error => {
      this.toast.warning(constants.LOGIN_ERROR);
    });
```

Comment: It give me the same result