# how to properly wait for a document in component inizialization

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angularfire

I'm struggling with this issue when an user logs in the dashboard for the first time in the session.

After login, I redirect the user to a private view retrieving its data from Firestore by using this service:

```
getUser():Observable<DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>> {
    const uid = this.user$?.uid;
    const userRef = doc(this.firestore,'users/' + uid)
    return from(
      getDoc(userRef)
    );
```

Then, in the Dashboard Layout Component, (Parent component for the rest of the module) I implement the service like so:

```
export class DashboardLayoutComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private auth:AuthService) {}

  public user:CustomUser;
  public loading:boolean =  true; 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.getUser().subscribe(res =>{
      this.luxorUser = res.data() as CustomUser;
      this.loading = false;
    });
}

}
```

When the user reaches the dashboard layout, the variable user is undefined. However, when I reload the page the data is properly assigned to the interface. Besides, some child components read the CustomUser Object with the @Output decorator, so they never show up because they are receiving an undefined instead of the Object.

Once I force reload, everything works as supposed.

**This is what I tried so far**

- Use Promises instead of Observables aiming to force async/await functions.
- In component.html I create a skeleton with the boolean variable loading to render the dashboard only when the function concludes. Loading gets updated, but CustomUser does not.
- Follow this topic : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324043/first-time-return-undefined-and-second-the-correct-result-how-can-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com)
- Call the service inside the constructor instead OnInit lifecycle.

**There is another approach I tried with identical result**

**Async call in service**

```
async getUser():Promise<CustomUser> {
    const uid = this.user$?.uid;
    const userRef = doc(this.firestore, 'users/' + uid );
    const snap = await getDoc(userRef);
    return snap.data() as CustomUser;
}
```

**In component**

```
export class DashboardLayoutComponent implements OnInit{

 constructor(private auth:AuthService) {}
 public $userData:Promise<CustomUser>
 public loading:boolean =  true; 

 ngOnInit(){
   this.retrieveUserData();
 }

 retrieveUserData() {
   this.$userData = this.auth.getUser();
 }

}
```

**In HTML**

```
    <div *ngIf="$userData | async" >
        <div class="layout-wrapper"  style="background-color: var(--surface-b);">
            <app-dashboard-topbar [user]="$userData | async" />
            <div class="layout-sidebar">
                <app-dashboard-sidebar/>
            </div>
            <div class="layout-main-container">
                <div class="layout-main">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="layout-mask"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would try create a Subject that triggers when user is logged to execute your `getUser` method

Comment: The variable name you use for the CustomUser declaration does not match the variable name of the object being set with the response data.  Is this a typo in your post or in your actual code?

Comment: The Subject approach is working in the same way than before for me. When I first login in the dashboard I get this error: (ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')). That's because the component tries to read the data before Firestore ends retrieving it. If I reload at this moment the data is already there so everything works just fine. I'm still trying to find a way to force the components to wait for the data.

Comment: Hi @Gallonallen. No, the property name is defined in the interface and exists in the DB. If the user has an active session everything works fine. It's happening only when he/she creates a new session when I can't force to retrieve data before the component tries to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a service with a Subject

```
...
isUser$ = new Subject<void>();
...
```

then

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.getUser().subscribe(res =>{
      this.luxorUser = res.data() as CustomUser;

      if ( this.luxorUser ) {

        this.subjectService.isUser$.next();        

        this.loading = false;

      }
    });
```

then in your component

```
this.subjectService.isUser$.pipe(
  tap( _ => this.userService.getUser()
).subscribe()
```